# Empty GET response on requesting JSON file's content | koa2

Tags: json, node.js, koa, koa2

I am a new to koa2, and I trying to GET the contents of a JSON file with koa2

```
app.use( async ( ctx ) => { 
  let url = ctx.request.url;
  if (url == "list") {
      let res = ctx.request.get('http://domain/hello.json');
      ctx.body = res.body;
  }
})
```

The JSON file `hello.json` looks like the following:

```
{"da": "1212", "dad": "12addsf12"}
```

I want the route `/list` to return the contents of `hello.json`, however, the response is empty. What do I do?

**Update**:
Change the following lines of code:

```
 let res = ctx.request.get('http://domain/hello.json');
 ctx.body = res.body;
```

to:

```
 let res = ctx.get('http://domain/hello.json');
 ctx.body = res;
```

You should get the content now.

Comment: You have defined a middleware, but where is the code which handles `/list` route path? Where is the JSON file hosted, within your public directory or in another domain?

Comment: Isn't `ctx.get()` just an alias for `ctx.request.get()`? I am curious now :-o

Answer (score 0):

Koa by itself does not support routing, only middleware, you need to have a router middleware for that, try [koa-router](https://github.com/koajs/route).

Your app would look something like

```
const route = require('koa-route')

app.use(route.get('/list', ctx => {
    // Route handling logic
});
```

Also note that `ctx.get` is an alias for `ctx.request.get` which returns header information.

Comment: Did you test this code? I still get an empty response. Try out my [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50218490/4350349)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be Koa's way of doing things, but this is what I tried and worked for me (complete code for noobs like me):

```
// jshint ignore: start
const koa2 = require("koa2");
const router = require('koa-simple-router');
const app = new koa2();
const request = require('request-promise-native');

// response
app.use(router(_ => {
    _.get('/list', async (ctx) => {
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            uri: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5af077a1310000540096c672'
        }
        await request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            // I am leaving out error handling on purpose, 
            // for brevity's sake. You must in your code.
            ctx.body = body;
        })
    });
}));

app.listen(3000);
```

And, like what [J Pichardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50218286/4350349) points out, Koa by itself does not support routing. You need to use some routing middleware.